# По нажатию на ссылку отправить post запрос с параметрами

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет. Целый день гуглю и пытаюсь сделать следующее:
по нажатию на ссылку DELETE, выполнялся delete_a_comment.php с пост данными $row["ID"].

```
echo '<div class="reply">
    <a id="delete_comment" data-id="'.$row["ID"].'"href="#" >delete</a>
</div>';
```

И все это без перезагрузки страницы. Средствами php знаю как. С jQuery мало опыта, вот знакомлюсь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без перезагрузки страницы - ajax. В объект data параметры, которые будут передаваться post'ом. success если ответ от сервера будет без ошибки. Параметр data содержит сам ответ.

```js
let btn = $('#delete_comment');
btn.click(()=> {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'delete_a_comment.php',
      data: { 
        id: $(btn).attr('data-id')
      },
      success: (data) => {
        //data - ответ сервера;
          console.log('ok');
        
      },
      error: (ex) =>{
      //Если ошибка
        console.log('err');
      }
      })
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="delete_comment" data-id="'.$row["ID"].'"href="#" >delete</a>
```

Comment: Благодарю!! Выручили!)

Answer (score 0):

```
$function () {
    var button = $('#delete_comment');
    button.click(function () {
        $.ajax({
           url     : 'ВАШ_URL',
           type    : 'post',
           data    : {
               id: button.data('id'),
           }
        });
    });
}
```